# Как задействовать скрипт и стиль только на одной странице?

Tags: wordpress, веб-дизайн, оптимизация-сайтов

Имею сайт **вордпресс**. Есть плагин, который работает только на одной странице.

Это конкретная страница, со своим урлом.

Я подкорректировал js+css.

Ну и вопрос как js+css подключить так, чтобы стили и скрипты **не читались** на тех страницах, где они не нужны, а только на той странице, где работает плагин, для которого предназначены скрипты и стили?

Comment: Не стоит назначать принятым неправильный ответ. Этим вы сбиваете с толку других пользователей, которые будут искать ответ на похожий вопрос. Правильный ответ дал Валерий Васильев.

Comment: да я от сам сомневался,.... хорошо что поправили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно деактивировать стили-скрипты в хуке wp_enqueue_scripts если условия не выполняются -  [wp_dequeue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/), [wp_dequeue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/)

Добавить данную функцию в functions.php активной темы

Пример отключения стилей-скриптов для страниц, где не используется плагин woocommerce

```
add_action(
            'wp_enqueue_scripts',
             function() {

                // Если это НЕ страницы магазина.
                if ( is_plugin_active("woocommerce/woocommerce.php") && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() && !is_account_page()) {
                    // Отключаем стили магазина.
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_frontend_styles' );
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-general');
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-layout' );
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-smallscreen' );
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_fancybox_styles' );
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_chosen_styles' );
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_prettyPhoto_css' );
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'select2' );
             
                    // Отключаем скрипты магазина.
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-payment-method' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-lost-password' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc_price_slider' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-credit-card-form' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart' ); 
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-chosen' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'woocommerce' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto-init' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-blockui' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-placeholder' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-payment' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'jqueryui' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'fancybox' );
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'wcqi-js' );
                }
            },
             99
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Если ты имеешь ввиду фразой ***не читались***, чтобы файл скрипта и файл стилей не скачивался, в шаблоне этой страницы в html вставь ссылку на подключаемый скрипт:

```
<script src="URL на файл скрипта"></script>
```

Чтобы файлы стилей подгрузились только при открытии этой страницы, то требуется в шаблоне сформировать блок head и в нем через link подключить файл стилей:

```
<head>
   ...тут контент блока head
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="URL на файл стилей">
</head>
```

Если же нет необходимости подкачивать файлы стилей и скриптов конкретно на этой странице, т.е. могут быть скачаны в любой момент, то и подключайте их в любой момент. Но, тогда стили должны содержать некий родительский класс, на основании которого они будут применяться к элементам, ну а этот некий родительский класс должен быть повешан на контейнер этой страницы, например на body:

```
css:
.special-page .title {
  ...стили для title специальной страницы
}

.special-page p {
  ...стили для всех paragraph специальной страницы
}
...и так далее
html:
<body class="special-page">
  ...контент блока body
</body>
```

Так стили применятся только к контенту на этой странице, на остальных страницах применения не будет.

Со скриптом все гораздо проще, надо просто в файле скрипта прописать проверку, например на URL страницы, или, если будет отличительный класс на странице, то попробовать найти элемент по классу:

```
script начало файла, или главной исполняемой функции:
const isspecialPage = Boolean(document.querySelector('.special-page'))
if (!isspecialPage) {
  return
}
```

В таком случае скрипт должен вызываться на каждой странице, но только один раз, эту логику думаю самостоятельно сможете написать.
Если страница не та, скрипт прекратит свое выполнение.

Comment: это неправильный ответ с точки зрения сайта на вордпресс. в экосистеме вордпресс есть ряд функций для деактивации загрузки скриптов-стилей еще на этапе выдачи страницы

Comment: Поддерживаю @ValeriiVasiliev. Ответ неправильный и вредный.

Comment: Ну отлично же, что есть вы, знатоки вордпресс ))
Просто я не работаю с ним и понятия не имею как у него устроена экосистема, и дал знать как можно такое сделать впринципе на страницах любого сайта.